# Argument error in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, class, initialization, sqlalchemy, typeerror

This is my first time using SQLalchemy. I have created a Newsletter class/table:

```py
class Newsletter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'newsletter'

    email = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime(timezone=False), default=datetime.utcnow,
                       server_default=expression.func.now())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '''<Newsletter('{email}', registered on: '{date}')>
               '''.format(email=self.email,
                          date=self.timestamp)

if__name__=='__main__':
    foobar = Newsletter('foobar@gmail.com')
```

But then received this error:

> TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Full code: http://dpaste.com/1313680

It was working earlier, and I have tried a bunch of different mutations to get it to work; to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inheriting the `__init__` method from the Base class which only allows for one argument `self`. You might want to change your class to.

```
class Newsletter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'newsletter'

    email = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime(timezone=False), default=datetime.utcnow,
                       server_default=expression.func.now())

   def __init__(self, email):
       self.emailID = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '''<Newsletter('{email}', registered on: '{date}')>
               '''.format(email=self.email,
                          date=self.timestamp)
```

**EDIT** - Instead of making a constructor inside the `NewsLetter` class, you could pass in a function to `declarative_base`.

If I'm getting the hang of it, then, to pass a constructor, you need to define a function, like so.

```
def constructorFunc(self, email):
    self.emailID = email
```

Then, just do `Base = declarative_base(constructor = constructorFunc)`

Comment: Mmm, I had something similar then the folks over on `#sqlalchemy` @ chat.freenode.net said (and I quote): >[supplicant] AlecTaylor: there's no need to create an explicit __init__ sqlalchemy defines one for you

Comment: Yes, the `Base` class does, but it allows for only one argument, if you need to pass in two arguments, you need to override the `__init__` method.

Comment: It looks like `declarative_base()` takes in parameters. See the link - [Here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base)

Comment: @AT : you could pass in a function to `declarative_base()` and that would work as the constructor.

Comment: What is the syntax for that?

Comment: Hmm, well that wouldn't have any LoC change when compared with adding an `__init__`…